# How to get value of systemuser entity?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Im not a JS developer but i have to work on it. I have a problem with getting the value from systemuser entity on save event. My intend is getting the territory value but the problem is it says "Bad Request" when i click on save. Im searching on the net but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Xrm.Page.context.getUserId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334511.aspx#Anchor_9) returns the guid of the current user including curly braces (e.g. `{B05EC7CE-5D51-DF11-97E0-00155DB232D0}`).

When calling the Web API, you should send the guid without curly braces (e.g. `/api/data/v8.1/systemusers(B05EC7CE-5D51-DF11-97E0-00155DB232D0)`).

You should thus strip the curly braces:

```
"/api/data/v8.1/systemusers(" + userid.slice(1, -1) + ")"
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right! But now im facing another issue. When script populates the subject field on save. I see text in the field for 1 sec. and then its disappearing.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Feel free to make a new question with only the code needed to reproduce your issue with the subject field clearing (I am thinking that you should be able to boil it down to a single line).